# how to Insert webcam stream in between two layers in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, flvplayback

In my flash project I  have 3 layers. 
back layer contain Flvplayback video
middle layer contain webcam stream
front layer contain flvplayback video(with Transparent background).

webcam stream video is also transparent.

I add the stream from following code.

```
webCam=Camera.getCamera();
webCam.setMode(appWidth/scale,appHeight/scale,60);
video=new Video(appWidth/scale,appHeight/scale);
video.smoothing=true;
video.attachCamera(webCam);
bmpdata=new BitmapData(appWidth/scale,appHeight/scale);
bmpdata_bg=new BitmapData(appWidth/scale,appHeight/scale);
bmp=new Bitmap(bmpdata);
bmp.smoothing=true;
bmp.x = 256;
bmp.y = 374;
addChild(bmp);
```

and I update that webcam stream using following function

```
function onFrameEnter(evt:Event):void {

 bmpdata.draw(video);

}
```

I want to know how to add this webcam stream to a middle layer and play it.
Is there any way to add this webcam stream to flvplayback in the middle layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it's impossible to refer to Flash IDE layers from Actionscript. There are a couple of workarounds you can do, though.

One is to have an empty instance movieclip in the desired layer with an instance name `mcStream`. Then, you can use `mcStream.addChild(bmp);`.

Another way is to refer to the item you want it to be under (we'll call it mcOverlay) and add it at its index. `addChildAt(bmp, getChildIndex(mcOverlay))` This will push add it where the overlay is and push the overlay on top of it.

I definitely recommend having a look at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/display_list_programming_as3.html